# Need to see sent post headers

Tags: debugging, post, network-programming, firebug, wireshark

I am trying to send a post request to google OAuth, and it is returning an invalid request. All the information I am sending is correct, so I want to see the post that I am sending (before it is sent), so that I can debug and see if and where the mistake is.

I am trying to use Wireshark or Firebug with no success. Maybe someone with some experience with this can point me in the right direction to seeing my post?

Thank you very much!

Comment: And what are you using to implement OAuth?

Comment: Python - but I just want to use httplib, so I am sending the post manually. I don't need the full oauth features

Comment: Then you should be looking at how you can make `httplib` spit out debug information you could use to figure out what you're doing wrong

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I will try to do that.

Comment: Where are you stuck concretely? "*[..] with no success*" is a broad statement. Have you reassembled the TCP stream when looking at the HTTP traffic?

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I found a solution that does not require me to see the headers. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it without use of any external program, the answer was that with Google OAuth you need to set the header such:

```
headers={'content-type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
```

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

What about http fox for firefox?

https://static-ssl-cdn.addons.mozilla.net/img/uploads/previews/full/18/18903.png?modified=1331247702

Or maybe there's a http-fire-bug-fox addon in the works somewhere?